# A question about multi step numerical methods and their characteristic polynomials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The following problem features in the book 'A First Course in the Numerical Analysis of Differential Equations' by Iserles.
[image]

In this context, we have 
$$
\rho(w) = \sum_{s=0}^{m}a_sw^s, \quad \sigma(w) = \sum_{s=0}^m b_s w^s.
$$
Part (a) is relatively straightforward. However, I cannot see how the result (2.18) in (b) was obtained. I tried to expand $w_1(z)$ as a Taylor series about $z=0$ in the formula
$$
\rho(w_1(z)) - z\sigma(w_1(z))  = \sum_{s=0}^m (a_s - zb_s) w_1^s(z) = 0,
$$
but this clearly doesn't take us anywhere. In particular, raising the expansion to the power $s$ will cause invevitable difficulties. The presence of the partial derivative in (2.18) would indicate another series expansion somewhere, but I'm not sure how it all comes together.

Can anyone explain how the given result is obtained? I'd very much appreciate it.